# How to save a Excel in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel sheet, and if I save the file using the `Save as...` option in Excel VBA the currently open document would close, and switch over to the newly created document.

How can I save a copy of the document without switching over the control?

Comment: I'll even type it out for you: find the best answer to your question and click arrow that appear on the upper left to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\myfile.xls", FileFormat:=52
Workbooks.Open CurrentFile
```

Comment: Workbooks.Open CurrentFile throwing error, can the full path of the file be included?  Looks like it's just the filename in CurrentFile.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SaveCopyAs to do what you want

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\XXXX.XLS"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="File Name", _
filefilter:="Excel Files,*.xls,All Files,*.*", _
Title:="Save As File Name")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.SaveAs Filename:=file_name
wb.Close
```